# Geometrical interpretation of $x^2y^2z^2$. How it is related to sphere.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, maxima-minima

Show that the maximum value of $x^2y^2z^2$ subject to the condition $x^2+y^2+z^2 = c^2$ is $\frac{c^6}{27}$. Interpret the result geometrically.

The above question is from Maxima and Minima concept of calculus. 
I am good with finding the maximum value.

But How to interpret geometrically. 
My approach is: 
The equation $x^2+y^2+z^2 = c^2$ represents a sphere with radius c.

I couldn't interpret the $x^2y^2z^2$. How it is related to above sphere.

please help me with the interpretation.

Comment: The key point is subject to $x^2+y^2+z^2=c^2$, so you are considering points on the sphere of radius $c$. Your result tells you that among all points on the sphere, the greatest value of $x^2y^2z^2$ that can be obtained is $c^6/27$.

Comment: You can also add in that by symmetry, the maximum is obtained on the line $x = y = z$, and thus occurs where this line intersects the sphere.